# How to rename single MultiIndex row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have the following MultiIndex DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Idx1"] = ["", "A", "B"]
df["Idx2"] = ["", "AA", "BB"]
df["Value"] = [1,2,3]
df = df.set_index(["Idx1", "Idx2"])

df
```

and I want to simply replace `("", "")` index by `("Total", "")` index. How can I do this leaving everything else unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option: the second level doesn't matter:

```
df = df.rename({'': 'Total'}, level='Idx1')
```

If you want to match both levels, create a new index:

```
idx = (df.index.to_series()
         .map(lambda x: {('', ''): ('Total', '')}.get(x, x))
      )
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(idx)
```

Output:

```
            Value
Idx1  Idx2       
Total           1
A     AA        2
B     BB        3
```

Comment: This solution (second one) doesnt preserve index names (it returns None, None) in my case

Comment: @Jason if you have index names you need to pass them as parameter to the MultiIndex constructor